# bash: http-server: command not found after install

Tags: javascript, npm, httpserver

When running the command `http-server` in a git-bash terminal I receive the error:

`bash: http-server: command not found`

This is after following the installation instructions on it's npm page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) and running the installation command `npm install --global http-server`.

It appears in my package.json file yet is just inaccessible. I could always use npx which seems to work but I would prefer to have it installed.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Issue this `npm list -g --depth=0` command and see if it's actually installed.

Comment: The result was this ```C:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── http-server@13.0.1```

So it looks like it is

Comment: I don't know what's the problem then. It may be that the path of http-server is not added to the terminal. But I use linux I don't know how to fix that on windows :(

Comment: Haha, no worries. Thank you for the quick reply. I will look to see if I can find any information about the terminal path.

Comment: By the way there is another package like this that I use. It's called `live-server`. Try this it it may not need path configuration. `npm i -g live-server` But I can't guarantee that it would work on windows.